# Returning a structure pointer(array) from a a function and printing out the data

Tags: c

I writing a piece of code that peoples information, store it in a binary file using a structure, then i use another function to write all the information in the file to structure array which i then return as a pointer.

when i call the function in main and assign the return value to a structure pointer i try to use pointer notation to iterate through the indexes and print the data. it does not give any errors but it prints garbage to the screen.

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct PersonRecords{
    char name[20];
    int age;
    char school[15];
}PERSON;

PERSON p1;

void UpdateRecords();
PERSON* FileToArray();

int main(){
    //UpdateRecords();

    PERSON* p3;
    p3 = FileToArray();
    while(p3!=NULL){
        printf("%s\t%i\t%s\n\n",(*p3).name,(*p3).age,(*p3).school);
        p3+=1;
    }
}

void UpdateRecords(){
    printf("Enter  person name: \n");
    fgets(p1.name,sizeof(p1.name),stdin);
    printf("Enter person age: \n");
    scanf("%f",&p1.age);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter person school: \n");
    fgets(p1.school,sizeof(p1.school),stdin);

    FILE* ptr;
    ptr = fopen("PersonRecords.dat","ab");
    fclose(ptr);
}

PERSON* FileToArray(){
    FILE* pt;
    int i = 0;
    pt = fopen("PersonRecords.dat","rb");
    static PERSON p2[250];
    while(fread(&p2[i],sizeof(PERSON),1,pt)!=0){
        i++;
    }
    fclose(pt);
return p2;
}
```

how do i print out the actual values in the array that i got from the file.
why am i practicing this? there is a part in the project that would benefit from something like this.

EDIT:

also what would be the best way to stop the loop in main when there is no more data?

Comment: What is the format of your `PersonRecords.dat` file?

Comment: new to writing c files. define format please and very much sorry

Comment: How do your create the `PersonRecords.dat`?

Comment: i created it using the `fopen();` function. using the `ab` mode. not sure if this answered your question

Comment: Show the exact code you used to create the file. BTW `scanf("%f", &p1.age);` should be `scanf("%d", &p1.age);`, `p1.age` is an `int`.

Comment: `
    FILE* ptr;
    ptr = fopen("PersonRecords.bin","ab");
    fclose(ptr);`

Comment: sorry i changed it to .bin before answering

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of posting code in comments. And the code you posted just creates an empty file. Read this [mcve].

Comment: thank you i see the issue now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want this. All comments are mine. The code is still extremely poor (for example there is no error checking at all, `fopen` can fail, unnecessary usage of global variables, fixed size `static PERSON p2` in `FileToArray` instead of dynamic memory allocation etc., etc.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct PersonRecords {
  char name[20];
  int age;
  char school[15];
}PERSON;

PERSON p1;

void UpdateRecords();
PERSON* FileToArray(int *nbofentries);

int main() {
  UpdateRecords();

  PERSON* p3;
  int nbofentries;
  p3 = FileToArray(&nbofentries);  // nbofentries will contain the number of entries read

  for (int i = 0; i < nbofentries; i++) {
    printf("%s\t%i\t%s\n\n", p3->name, p3->age, p3->school);  // instead of (*x).y write x->y
    p3 += 1;
  }
}


void UpdateRecords() {
  printf("Enter  person name: \n");
  fgets(p1.name, sizeof(p1.name), stdin);
  printf("Enter person age: \n");
  scanf("%d", &p1.age);
  fgetc(stdin);                   // you need to add this (scanf is quite a special function)
  printf("Enter person school: \n");
  fgets(p1.school, sizeof(p1.school), stdin);

  FILE* ptr;
  ptr = fopen("PersonRecords.dat", "ab");
  fwrite(&p1, 1, sizeof(p1), ptr);      // actually writes something to the file
  fclose(ptr);
}

PERSON* FileToArray(int *nbofentries) {
  FILE* pt;
  int i = 0;
  pt = fopen("PersonRecords.dat", "rb");
  static PERSON p2[250];
  while (fread(&p2[i], sizeof(PERSON), 1, pt) != 0) {
    i++;
  }
  fclose(pt);

  *nbofentries = i;   // return the number of entries read to the caller
  return p2;
}
```